# How can I compare two stored texts in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

How can I compare two stored texts and if they are equal to echo some result?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `verifyEval` command to compare two variables:

```
store | text | i
store | different text | j
verifyEval | storedVars['i']==storedVars['j'] | true
```

Running this script as written will cause the test to fail with `[error] Actual value 'false' did not match 'true'`. Change `j` to `text`, and it will complete without error.

Note that this can also be used to verify that two strings are not equal, by changing `true` to `false` in the `verifyEval` command.

Comment: This is the right answer. And, it's simple too. Thanks.

Comment: this what I dislike about Selenium...well, at least its documentation anyway...verifyEval is no longer available in 3.17...there's no reference as what's the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

As of 3.17 IDE for Chrome:

Command Target     Value

assert variableX ${variableY}

IMPORANT: the target does NOT need ${}...or you'll get a null